# SQL Server 2019 perform volume maintenance enabled during installation but not visible in local policies

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2019

I played around with a new `SQL Server 2019 Developer` and noticed something strange. I enabled `Perform volume maintenance tasks` during installation and setup the engine to use a domain account, but after installation the service account is not visible in `Local Security Policies`. I checked using the below query and also in the log, and it looks ok.

Any idea why the service account is not showing up in Local policies?

```
select instant_file_initialization_enabled ,* 
from sys.dm_server_services
where servicename like 'SQL Server%'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea why the service account is not showing up in Local policies?

It uses the per service sid, when you change the account it'll still work. You can see this in your screenshot.